# Emploi de voix passive comme dans "Un carré est translaté" pour "A square is translated"

Tags: participe-passé, passif

Je sais que la voix passive semble souvent bizarre aux locuteurs natifs.
Cependant, il y a des cas qu'on ne peut pas éviter.
Pour plusieurs raisons ("captions" des figures, titles des sections, discours) je voudrais rendre en français des tournures anglaises comme

> A unit cube is translated, rotated and deformed.
>
> Unit cube translated, rotated and deformed.

Je pense aux tournures

> Un cube unité est translaté, tourné et déformé. (1)
>
> Cube unité translaté, tourné et déformé. (2)

Mes collègues me disent que les tournures françaises sont gauches et le participe passé *translaté* est peu usité, voir inconnu et qu'il faut utiliser la structure avec le pronom *on*.

> On translate, tourne et déforme un cube unité.

Ont-ils raison ? Je sais qu'on peut aussi dire

> Translation, rotation et déformation d'un cube unité

mais je me demande pourquoi les tournures (1) et (2) ne se disent pas quoiqu'elles soient grammaticalement correctes ?

Comment: Oui, ils ont raison.

Comment: LaureSO-Écoute-nous Si on veut utiliser ces tournures pour le titre d'un section, pour la caption d'une figure ou bien pour un legende d'une figure ? Je ne crois pas que on peut éviter cube unité translaté, tourné et déformé

Comment: Pour un titre (que ce soit de section ou de légende) je pense qu'on ne mettrait ni passif ni « on » mais un substantif, par ex. « Translation, rotation et déformation d'un cube unité ».

Comment: @LaureSO-Écoute-nous Merci ! Du point de vue de la grammaire il n'y pas de faute avec *Un cube unité est translaté, tourné et déformé* et *Cube unité translaté, tourné et déformé*, n'est-ce pas ? C'est qu'elles sonnent (sorry for the anglicisme:-)!) bizarre aux oreilles des locuteurs natifs ?

Comment: Non, il n'y a pas de faute du point de vue grammatical, c'est juste que ça ne se dit pas en français. Au fait, *caption* (ton commentaire précédent) ne s'emploie pas en français dans ce sens là. Légende (éventuellement dans certains cas titre).

Comment: L'exemple de la phrase en anglais mériterait plus de contexte. Comme tel, la phrase est un peu bizarre. Moins bizarre serait. A unit cube **may be** A, B or C.

Comment: Cela parait bizarre dans le langage courant. En revanche, dans le langage mathématique, je l'ai déjà utilisé et entendu. Le *on* n'est pas toujours adapté dans ce contexte, le carré est en général translaté par une fonction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Il me semble que dans ce cas les conseil  de vos collègues sont justifiés ; cependant, il est hâtif de leur part d'appeler les tournures maladroites. On peut invoquer la raison suivante : la voix passive peut parfois être empreinte d'une perception parasitique qui donne l'idée qu'elle est partiellement annulée, pas vraiment effective, le lecteur pouvant s'interroger s'il ne s'agit pas plutôt d'une voix active où « être » n'est plus l'auxiliaire mais le verbe d'état.

- La table est débarrassée.

Est-ce  que l'on a dit par cette phrase qu'il n'y a plus rien sur la table ou bien qu'à un moment particulier quelqu'un débarrasse la table ? On ne le sait que d'après le contexte qui ici fait totalement défaut.

Sans trop incriminer la voix passive dans le contexte des phrase de la question originelle, on reconnait que l'usage de la voix passive sera très minoritaire dans ce contexte et on peut soi-même  trouver ces phrases bizarres ou lourdes mais il sera difficile pour le non spécialiste de dire pourquoi. C'est un sujet sur lequel, je dois l'avouer, je n'ai jamais lu un avis d'expert —il n'y en a que peu—, et donc sur je lequel je n'en possède pas moi-même.

- Le pain est sorti du four puis mis à refroidir ; il est ensuite coupé en tranches d'un seul coup par un instrument  à lames multiples en rotation et immédiatement et il est introduit dans son sachet d'emballage ; c'est ainsi qu'il restera jusqu'à ce qu'il arrive sur nos tables.

On trouve d'innombrables phrases telle que celle de l'exemple précédent et je vous assure qu'elles ne produisent pas l'effet d'être construites avec des tournures maladroites : c'est bien la voix passive qui y est utilisée. Il y a donc un élément d'apparente subjectivité qui rend la voix passive peu attrayante dans certain cas et on ne peut pas écarter complètement le manque d'habitude comme responsable. On remarquera que lorsqu'un enseignant français émet un jugement sur la voix passive comme on la trouve en anglais il s'en tient assez souvent à une formulation de la sorte « La langue anglaise est une langue qui n'aime pas (trop) la voix passive. ». Une formulation similaire convient au français : « Le français est une langue qui dans certains contextes répugne à la voix passive. ».

Le pronom « on » est donc ici un choix approprié.

Comment: Merci. Je n'arrive pas à comprendre pourquoi dans un contexte clair (de la mécanique) la tournure "(Un) cube unité (est) translated, rotated and deformed." ne se dit pas et il nous faut remplace avec "On translate, tourne et déforme un cube unité" ou bien "(La) translation, rotation et déformation d'un cube unité". Pourquoi apprend-il la voix passive si nous pouvons l'utiliser ?

Comment: @Dimitris 1/ J'ai essayé de vous l'expliquer, la raison n'est pas bien claire et personne ne l'explique vraiment. Tout ce que l'on peut dire c'est que dans certains cas l'emploi est reconnu comme tout à fait normal et que dans d'autres il ne l'est pas. 2/ Il pourrait être argué comme dans l'exemple de la table que je donne. 3/ Vous basez votre raisonnement sur l'anglais comme c'est une langue qui vous parle plus pour l'instant, donc prenons le cas de l'anglais : n'apprend-on pas une voix passive en anglais ? Vous savez pourtant qu'en anglais on l'évite souvent ; c'est similaire en français.

Comment: Grâce à votre réponse et les commentaires de Laure c'est plus claire. Dans le contexte mathématique/mécanique je crois qu'en anglais (j'ai rédigé des articles scientifiques et j'ai lu une pléthore de livres) on n'essaie pas d'éviter la voix passive.

Comment: @Dimitris Vos remarques nous montrent donc qu'il y aurait très possiblement quelque chose de subjectif dans ces usages.

Answer (score 3):

J'ai posté la question sur un autre forum :

https://www.question-orthographe.fr/question/emploi-de-la-voix-passive/

Voici une réponse que j'ai obtenue qui mérite d'être incluse ici. (Il y en a deux autres.)

> Votre question porte surtout sur la rédaction de titres, me semble-t-il, et de titres d’articles (ou simplement de textes) scientifiques ; ce qui est un cas particulier.
>
> Le français n’a aucune aversion pour la forme passive, qu’on rencontre très fréquemment dans toutes sortes de textes : récits, documentaires, textes argumentatifs, explicatifs, scientifiques… , et à  l’écrit comme à l’oral.
>   On la trouve notamment souvent dans des titres d’articles de journaux.
>
> Exemples : Sauvé par son chien – Blessés par l’explosion de…
>
> Mais il semble qu’on évite cette forme passive dans les titres des textes scientifiques.
>
> Un cube unité est translaté, tourné et déformé – Cube unité translaté, tourné et déformé
>
> Pourquoi ?
>   La forme passive met l’accent sur le résultat et non le processus qui est décrit par le texte scientifique qui suit.
>
> On évite aussi l’emploi du pronom »on » :
>
> On translate, tourne et déforme un cube unité
>
> Pourquoi ?
>   Parce que, même si le pronom « on » est indéfini on met l’accent sur l’agent et c’est inutile.
>
> On préfèrera nettement la nominalisation que vous proposez :
>
> Translation, rotation et déformation d’un cube unité
>
> Parce que là, ce qui est mis en évidence, c’est le processus lui-même.